# Prevent Firefox from creating ~/Desktop folder

Tags: firefox

I don't like having `Desktop` folder in my home directory. But even though I remove it, Firefox keeps creating the empty `~/Desktop` directory each time I run it. I use Firefox 57 on Arch Linux.

How can I disable this behavior of Firefox?

Comment: Did you try overriding the directory name in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`?

Comment: I don't have a file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. Should I create one?

Comment: Which desktop environment are you using?

Comment: None. I'm only running i3 windows manager on Xorg.

Comment: Do you have the rest of the XDG direcotries, e.g. `~/Documents`, `~/Templates`, etc.?

Comment: Okay, I installed `xdg-user-dirs` Arch package and now I have `~/config/user-dirs.dirs`. I changed `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"` to `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME"`, but Firefox still creates `~/Desktop` directory when I run it. **EDIT**: No, it works :). So thanks for pointing the solution for me!

Comment: @Robert If you've managed to solve your problem now, you may wish to answer your own question (write an answer, then mark it as accepted) or delete your question.

Comment: Here's a related mozilla bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1082717

Answer (score 1):

As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams pointed, Firefox is using `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR` variable from `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`, so the solution is to edit the value of that variable. Sometimes it might require installing XDG package, e.g. `xdg-user-dirs` on Arch.

As Jon pointed, there is a Firefox [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1082717), which describes some problems with the mentioned solution.